# Regex to find a particular word enclosed between commas python

Tags: python, regex

I have string like `((,"ab"  ,,, , ,AND,,, ,,   "cd"  ,OR  "ef"  NOT, , "gh",))`. The words AND, OR,NOT can be either preceded, enclosed or followed by single of multiple commas. The comma itself can contain space between them.

I want the final  string as `((,"ab" AND   "cd" OR  "ef" NOT "gh",))`.  The regex I have tried is

```
(^|,+)AND|OR|NOT(?=,+|$)
```

But this is only able to capture ',AND'. How do I change my regex to even consider the commas which is followed by space and how do I capture the commas after the matched word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `re.sub`:

```sh
import re
s = '((,"ab"  ,,, , ,AND,,, ,,   "cd"  ,OR  "ef"  NOT, , "gh",))'
r = re.sub(r'[\s,]+(AND|OR|NOT)[\s,]+', r' \1 ', s)
print (r)
```

**Output:**

```
((,"ab" AND "cd" OR "ef" NOT "gh",))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNgVQ2/1)

- `[,\s]+` matches 1+ of comma or whitespaces.
- `(AND|OR|NOT)` = matches and captures these 3 words in group #1

Comment: This is exactly i was looking for